# Using Multiple Phone Numbers with a cell phone

Tags: asterisk

How difficult will it be to setup multiple phone numbers for different groups of people. When someone calls a number it should ring my phone. When I call someone it should show the caller id as being the number for the group the given target is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to setup a mini call center like system in Asterisk ,

It is easy to an extent , if you are familiar with Linux and IP telephony ,

[Here is the tutor which I had tried long back](http://cssucs.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/simple-call-center-setup-call-queuing-agents-in-asterisk/) . IF you want to familiarize yourself with Asterisk you can [follow this tutor](http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/)